# Using Go's echo framework, how would I write a file when the service successfully starts?

Tags: rest, go

In echo framework, I start the service with the following:

```
router.Start(...)
```

That call blocks because it is serving. What I want to do is create a file called /tmp/heathy when the service has successfully started.

I wrote something like this and added it to init()

```
func writeHealthyFile() {
    err := os.WriteFile("/tmp/healthy", []byte("healthy"), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("failed to write health file %v", err)
    }
}
```

but that has the drawback of being written **before** the service starts. I need to write the file after the service successfully starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create server in a new goroutine. Have seen this approach used for http to https redirect and graceful shutdown.

Below can work for you.

```golang
var wg sync.WaitGroup
e := echo.New()
e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "OK")
})

wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    if err := e.Start(":8080"); err != nil {
        e.Logger.Fatal("shutdown")
    }
}()

writeHealthyFile()
wg.Wait()
```

[http to https redirect](https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/860#issuecomment-302791018)
[graceful shutdown](https://echo.labstack.com/docs/cookbook/graceful-shutdown)